# Consulta en ajax

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    var click = $('.click');
    click.on('click', function () {
        var id = $(this).data('id');
        usuario = '<?php $idMesero;?>';
        for (var i = 1; i <= 14; i++) {
            switch (id) {
                case i:
                    //$('#' + id).addClass(presionado);
                    //time(id);
                    var request = $.ajax({
                        method: 'GET',
                        url: '../php/funciones.php', //el archivo server .php al que quieres enviar                    
                        data: {
                            dato: id,
                            user: usuario //dato que quieres enviar
                        },
                        dataType: 'json' //el tipo de dato tambien puede ser text
                    });

                    request.done(function (response) {
                        if (response.status) {
                            alert('Success: ' + response.result + "\n Message: " + response.message);
                            //window.location.href = '../php/ordena.php';
                        } else {
                            alert('Error: ' + response.message);
                            //window.location.href = window.location.href;
                        }
                    });

                    request.fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
                        alert("Server request failed: " + textStatus);
                        //window.location.href = '';
                    });
                    break;
            }
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<?php
    require 'conexion.php';
    #require 'login.php';
    require 'include/datosHamburguesas.php';

if(isset($_GET) && isset($_GET['dato'] && isset($_GET['usuario'])){
    header('Content-Type: application/json');

    $identificador = $_GET['dato'];
    $usuario = $_GET['usuario'];
    if($identificador == 1){
        $inserta = "INSERT INTO $comanda (idComanda, idEmpleado, idProductos, fechaCom, noMesa, cantidadProd) 
                                VALUES (3, $usuario, $idH, CURDATE(), 20, 1)";
        $con->query($inserta);
        echo json_encode(array(//pruebas si funciona imprimiendolo
            'status' => 1,
            'result' => $identificador,
            'message' => "listo"
        ), true);
    }
}
?>
```

quiero obtener un registro de una tabla con ajax y, luego poder pasarlo a otro archivo php.
Osea en una tabla tengo el id de un usuario y, lo quiero recuperar con ajax para despues poder usarlo en un insert, en otro archivo php.

Comment: y que haz intentado? necesitas poner lo que haz hecho

Comment: Pues ya lo recuperé en un select, en otro archivo php, el problema es que cuando dicho campo que recuperé lo quiero pasar a un insert, para poder agregarlo a otra tabla, me marca parsererror.
Si pongo un valor constante sí me genera el insert, pero si quiero usar un valor que ya obtuve de otra consulta no. Espero haberme explicado.

Comment: necesitas añadir tu código para que los usuarios te apoyen mejor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Que te parece una variable de sessión?

Supongamos que este sea tu primer código donde recuperas el ID del usuario

```
<?php 
$query = "SELECT ID FROM EMPLEADOS WHERE NOMBRE = 'FOO'";
if( $resultado = mysqli_query($con,$query)){

  if( mysqli_num_rows( $resultado ) > 0){
    $fila = mysqli_fetch_array( $resultado );
    //Aquí hacemos la variable de sesión, iniciamos sesión y creamos una nueva variable
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['id'] = $fila['ID'];
  }
  mysqli_free_result( $resultado );
  mysqli_close( $con );
}
?>
```

Ahora tu `INSERT` quedaría así

```
<?php
    //Inicias tu sesión
    session_start();
    require 'conexion.php';
    require 'include/datosHamburguesas.php';

if(isset($_GET) && isset($_GET['dato'] && isset($_GET['usuario'])){
    header('Content-Type: application/json');

    $identificador = $_GET['dato'];

    //Ahora en lugar de enviar el ID, recuperamos con la sessión del servidor
    $usuario = $_SESSION['id'];
    if($identificador == 1){
        $inserta = "INSERT INTO $comanda (idComanda, idEmpleado, idProductos, fechaCom, noMesa, cantidadProd) 
                                VALUES (3, $usuario, $idH, CURDATE(), 20, 1)";
        $con->query($inserta);
        echo json_encode(array(//pruebas si funciona imprimiendolo
            'status' => 1,
            'result' => $identificador,
            'message' => "listo"
        ), true);
    }
}
?>
```

Creo que sería más práctico hacerlo de esa forma y ya no te peleas con el FRONT

**EDITO**

Ya vi el error, estas tratando de recuperar una variable que no existe

```
//El índice usuario en el GET no existe, debería ser user
$identificador = $_GET['dato'];
$usuario = $_GET['user'];

data: {
 dato: id,
 user: usuario //dato que quieres enviar
},
```

Puedes comprobar en tu PHP si haces `var_dump($GET);`

Comment: cierto no noté ese error, intentaré eso, y a cómo dices de no pelearme con el front, la razón es que cuándo yo le de click a una imagen, se hará la consulta, y luego se hará el insert con los campos que se definieron arriba en el código cómo variable, probaré tú solución compañero xD

Answer (score 2):

Te comento que lo puedes hacer con la función post, en el siguiente ejemplo pasas los valores a "ejemplo_ajax_proceso.php"

```js
<html>
 
<head>
 
<title>Ejemplo sencillo de AJAX</title>
 
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.js"></script>
 
<script>
function realizaProceso(valorCaja1, valorCaja2){
        var parametros = {
                "valorCaja1" : valorCaja1,
                "valorCaja2" : valorCaja2
        };
        $.ajax({
                data:  parametros,
                url:   'ejemplo_ajax_proceso.php',
                type:  'post',
                beforeSend: function () {
                        $("#resultado").html("Procesando, espere por favor...");
                },
                success:  function (response) {
                        $("#resultado").html(response);
                }
        });
}
</script>
 
</head>
 
<body>
```